# Powershell. Get-content for every file

Tags: powershell

```
get-content .\old\*.edifact | foreach-object {$a = get-random; $_ -replace ('TEST4', $a)} | out-file .\new\$a.edifact
```

Problem that after this i'am getting 1 file with ALL lines from files from old folder.

**What i need:** change all lines which contain TEST4 by random value and after this operation create new files for every old file with random value also.

**old file:** blabalb.edifact, line EDSLDK
**new file:** 23423423423.edifact, line 342342342

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, if you want to go though every file in the old directory and replace in the contents 'TEST-4' with a random number then output to a new directory then try this:

```
Get-Childitem -Path .\old -Filter *.edifact | % {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | % {
    $_ -Replace ('TEST-4', (Get-Random).ToString())
  } | out-file (Join-Path '.\new' $_.Name)
}
```

Comment: If it's OK to replace all occurrences of 'TEST-4' in one file with the same random number, the loop could be eliminated like this: `(Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace 'TEST-4', (Get-Random).ToString() | Out-File ...`